# How does native string substitution work in js?

Tags: javascript, string

In a piece of code I've found I noticed someone has used not only the "normal" `%s` but also `%j`. I've heard of the `%s` being referred to as "native string substitution" similarly to how `sprintf` works in other languages.

Can all letters be used after a `%` to denote where a string is to be replaced? Are there certain rules for how each letter would work as in are the `%s` going to be replaced with the same var but the `%j` would be replaced with a different one or are they all the same?

For example.

```
console.info(
    '%s:%s/%s question:%j answer:%j',
    req.connection.remoteAddress,
    req.connection.remotePort,
    req.connection.type,
    question,
    answer
);
```

Comment: that's a chrome devtools console syntax that might be adopted by other browsers. the "letter" indicates the data type for formatting, the substution is purely in-order, not dependant on the types

Comment: Do you happen to know the name of this or where documentation can be found as so far I can only find docs on .replace() and not on console.log()

Comment: ECMAScript has [*string template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The notation in the OP is from the console host object, which allows formatting where the relevant [*API*](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/) is supported (which may not be ubiquitous or consistent). Also see [*MDN: console*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Usage).

Comment: there's a huge document on the console's features somewhere. look for console.table

Comment: @RobG that's what I was looking for, since I didn't know what this kind of thing was called I couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: You may need to keep searching. Host objects are pretty much allowed to do whatever they like provided they are roughly consistent with ECMA-262. The console has come a long way in a short time, it's a rapidly evolving component. ;-)